# Select column from rows and store them

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I want to store values from multiple rows so that I can reuse them. 
The following retrieves all id's in rows where a condition is met:

```
SELECT @userId = `id` FROM `user` WHERE `active` = '1'
```

Once I have those id's, I want to insert in a different table, new rows per id that I found in the previous statement:

```
//per id that was found    
INSERT INTO `test` (`testField`, `userid`) VALUES ('x', @userid);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply insert all rows as follows:

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`testField`, `userid`)
 select 'x', id FROM `user` WHERE `active` = '1';
```

No need to store value each row data into variable then insert into table.

Comment: That is interesting. So the values added are coming directly from the Select statement and the 'x' can be statically added?

Comment: yeah..'x' is statically added but you can change it to some other column coming from `user` table or you may insert row number. all those things depends on your requirement.